# Storing dates using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a sheet called 'Data,' and in Column A of this sheet, there are various text values, blank values, and date values. I'm trying to find a way to copy each of the date values in Column A of 'Data' and paste it into the first row of another sheet 'Chart.' The end result I'm looking for is to create a chart with column headings for each of the dates. There's more to do with the chart that I've been piecing together little-by-little, but I'm pretty stuck on how to accomplish the column headings.

The main piece I'm looking for is how to copy each of just the date values. I've looked a bit into the Find function, but I can't quite get it to hone in on only date values.

Thank you so much for any help!

Cheers,
B

Comment: Can you post what your data looks like and what you have tried so far?

Comment: If the cell containing a date is NOT formatted as a date there could be trouble, is the date always formatted properly?

Comment: How about testing each cell with `ISDATE` ?  (ref: [TechOnTheNet](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isdate.php))

Comment: @PeterT that's what I meant by there could be trouble, if the cell contains a date but is formatted as a number `ISDATE` returns false

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub Answer()

Dim DestWS As Worksheet
Dim DestCol As Integer
Dim ColumnA As Variant

Set DestWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Chart")
ColumnA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Columns(1)

DestCol = 1
For Each c In ColumnA
   If IsDate(c) Then
      DestWS.Cells(1, DestCol) = c
      DestCol = DestCol + 1
   End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That looks like it will error because you have not initialized `DestCol`.

Comment: @Brian right-o! Thanks, Good catch, that's what I get for not testing the code.